# Gensim -- [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'model.wv'

Tags: python, model, gensim

I've got a question during following the simple gensim tutorial on [gensim website](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html),

```
>>> from gensim.test.utils import common_texts, get_tmpfile
>>> from gensim.models import Word2Vec
>>>
>>> path = get_tmpfile("word2vec.model")
>>>
>>> model = Word2Vec(common_texts, size=100, window=5, min_count=1, workers=4)
>>> model.save("word2vec.model")
>>> model = Word2Vec.load("word2vec.model")
>>> model.train([["hello", "world"]], total_examples=1, epochs=1)

>>> from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
>>>
>>> path = get_tmpfile("wordvectors.kv")
>>>
```

And when I tried below,

```
>>> model.wv.save(path)
>>> wv = KeyedVectors.load("model.wv", mmap='r')
```

I've got a following error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-eee6865b677b> in <module>
      1 path = get_tmpfile('wordvectors.kv')
      2 model.wv.save(path)
----> 3 KeyedVectors.load("model.wv",mmap='r')

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py in load(cls, fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
    210     @classmethod
    211     def load(cls, fname_or_handle, **kwargs):
--> 212         return super(BaseKeyedVectors, cls).load(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
    213 
    214     def similarity(self, entity1, entity2):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py in load(cls, fname, mmap)
    420         compress, subname = SaveLoad._adapt_by_suffix(fname)
    421 
--> 422         obj = unpickle(fname)
    423         obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)
    424         logger.info("loaded %s", fname)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py in unpickle(fname)
   1356 
   1357     """
-> 1358     with smart_open(fname, 'rb') as f:
   1359         # Because of loading from S3 load can't be used (missing readline in smart_open)
   1360         if sys.version_info > (3, 0):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py in smart_open(uri, mode, **kw)
    179         raise TypeError('mode should be a string')
    180 
--> 181     fobj = _shortcut_open(uri, mode, **kw)
    182     if fobj is not None:
    183         return fobj

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py in _shortcut_open(uri, mode, **kw)
    299     #
    300     if six.PY3:
--> 301         return open(parsed_uri.uri_path, mode, buffering=buffering, **open_kwargs)
    302     elif not open_kwargs:
    303         return open(parsed_uri.uri_path, mode, buffering=buffering)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'model.wv'
```

Does anyone know the reason for this message? How can I know that I do have 'model.wv' file?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it from:  `wv = KeyedVectors.load("model.wv", mmap='r')`

to: `wv = KeyedVectors.load(path, mmap='r')`

You should be loading the file `'wordvectors.kv'`

Comment: I've reported the error in gensim's documentation <https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html> as a bug <https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2669>.